# How to display the foreign key and many-to-many fields in Django admin `list_display`?

Tags: django, django-admin

How to display the foreign key and many-to-many fields in Django admin `list_display`?

**models.py:**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)

class Character(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='character')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Author(models.Model):
    book = models.ManyToManyField(Book, related_name='author')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**admin.py:**

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'characters', 'authors')

    def characters(self, obj):
        ???

    def authors(self, obj):
        ???
```

Comment: Display it how? As a comma-separated list or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch the related `character`s/`author`s and then join the names in a comma separated list:

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'characters', 'authors')

    def characters(self, obj):
        return ', '.join([c.name for c in obj.character.all()])

    def authors(self, obj):
        return ', '.join([a.name for a in obj.author.all()])
```

We can boost performance by using [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to fetch all related objects in bulk:

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'characters', 'authors')

    def characters(self, obj):
        return ', '.join([c.name for c in obj.character.all()])

    def authors(self, obj):
        return ', '.join([a.name for a in obj.author.all()])

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).prefetch_related(
            'character', 'author'
        )
```

Since the `related_name` is the relation in reverse, and there can be *multiple* `Character`s/`Author`s, it makes sense to give these a *plural* name.