# Django admin display many-to-many field as links

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Trying to get my Django admin to display a list of related objects as hyperlinks to those objects. These objects are related through a many-to-many relationship.

Using a combination of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67043558/7656164) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37539948/7656164), I came up with:

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    related = models.ManyToManyField(RelatedObject)

class RelatedObject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=191)

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("rel")

    def rel(self, obj):
        return[self.link_to_object(related_object) for related_object in obj.related.all()]

    def link_to_object(self, obj):
        link = reverse("admin:<app>_relatedobject_change", args=[obj.id])
        return format_html(f"<a href={link}>{obj.name}</a>")
```

However, this gives me a [list of hrefs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAg2Z.png), not a list of links.

If I instead change:

```
    def rel(self, obj):
        return self.link_to_object(obj.related.get(pk=1))
```

It returns a nice link (where that relationship exists), but I can't get this to replicate when multiple objects are retrieved.

Is there a way to get admin to return a list of hyperlinks?

I'll note that there's also this [linkify method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53092940/7656164) floating around, but it only works for a ForeignKey, not many-to-many, and I don't see how to adapt it.

Comment: For anyone interested, i've used @Aa19's answer to update [linkify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77113885/1798234) to also handle ManyToManyFields

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any other right way, but I did it using the HTML list tag:

```
def rel(self, obj):
    return self.links_to_objects(obj.related.all())

@classmethod
def links_to_objects(cls, objects):
    rel_list = "<ol>"
    for obj in objects:
        link = reverse("admin:<your_app>_<your_rel_model_lower>_change", args=[obj.id])
        rel_list += "<li><a href='%s'>%s</a></li>" % (link, obj.name)
    rel_list += "</ol>"
    return format_html(rel_list)
```

Comment: I no longer have access to the codebase where I had this problem, so I can't confirm your answer works. Thank you for answering though!

Comment: This works like a charm! For clarity add the imports `from django.urls import reverse` and `from django.utils.html import format_html`